# How to Write MemoryStream to End of Text File

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I've used this code to write memorystream data to text file.

```
 Dim memoryStrm As New MemoryStream()
        Dim writer As New StreamWriter(memoryStrm)
      Dim thefile As New FileStream(Application.StartupPath & "\DocsLog" & ".txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)

            ' now Write the MemoryStream to the file
            memoryStrm.WriteTo(theFile)
```

But when I write data to the text file, I loose it's previous contents. How should I write memorystream to end of the text file? (only add memorystream data to end of the file)

Comment: If you can't change your code what kind of help do you expect? If you could you may use constructor that takes Append mode...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do

```
theFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)
```

Before writing anything

Answer (score 3):

Use one of the `FileStream` constructors that takes `FileMode` and specify `FileMode.Append` instead of `FileMode.Open`. I.e. using simple [contructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 Dim thefile As FileStream = _
        new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append)
```

And then copy source stream to destination with [Stream.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Copying begins at the current position in the current stream, and does not reset the position of the destination stream after the copy operation is complete.

```
memoryStrm.CopyTo(theFile);
```

Notes:

- make sure to properly dispose streams (i.e. with `using` in C#)
- copying bytes from the memory stream may break encoding if encodings don't match. If both are indeed text files with unknown encoding you may be better of reading text content and re-creating file with concatenated text.
- watch out for BOM in beginning of your memory stream.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change FileMode.Open to FileMode.Append.